# How to pass custom property when running jmeter via java code without editing the jmx file

Tags: java, jmeter

I have tried my best but I had no luck in looking for a solution. Basically I needed to pass **custom property** when running Jmeter via java code without adding anything in the jmx file (just like when running via command line). I have some tried jmeter property functions (StandardJmeterEngine setProperty, JmeterUtils setProperty) but still no avail. I have seen some solutions like passing the property file to the code but it seems that the property file is not being read.

By the way, the easiest way to do this is to create the jmx file along with the properties via java code, but I am required to pass the property when running an existing jmx file.

```
public class TestRunJmxJava {

    @Test
    public static void executeScript() throws IOException, BiffException, JMeterEngineException {

        String slash = System.getProperty("file.separator");
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();

        String jmeterPath = "C:"+slash+"jmeter"+slash+"bin"+slash+"jmeter.properties";
        String uPath = "C:"+slash+"jmeter"+slash+"bin"+slash+"jd.properties";

        System.out.println(jmeterPath);

        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("C:\\jmeter");
        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties(jmeterPath);
        JMeterUtils.loadProperties(uPath);

        JMeterUtils.getSearchPaths();
        JMeterUtils.initLogging();
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();

        SaveService.loadProperties();

        File in = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+slash+"jmxfolder"+slash+"TestJmeterRun.jmx");
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);

        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        FileServer.getFileServer().setBasedir(System.getProperty("user.dir")+slash+"jmxfolder");
        System.out.println(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir());

        Summariser summer = null;
        String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");//$NON-NLS-1$
        if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
            summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
        }

        String logFile = "C:\\Users\\JD\\Desktop\\sample2.jtl";

        ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
        logger.setFilename(logFile);

        testPlanTree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);

        jmeter.run();
        jmeter.exit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "normal" [Java System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) for this, they can be set in different ways:

- Via *system.properties* file (lives in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
- Via [-D command-line argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) passed to Java executable

  ```
  java -Dfoo=bar -jar /path/to/your/test.jar
  ```
- Via Java code by calling [System.setProperty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method

  ```
  System.setProperty("foo", "bar");
  ```

In all cases you should be able to access the property value like `${__P(foo,)}` (make sure you include `ApacheJMeter_functions.jar` in your project classpath)

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I wanted to try the system properties, but I'm thinking that if I am about to run all the jmx scripts in parallel, and I need to property value to be different in one script, and different on another script, conflicts might occur. I currently searching for a way to set the property on a local thread only, but if you have an idea in mind, please tell me, it will be much appreciated.