# ${__P(thread,1) doesn't work in my JMX file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

${__P(thread,1)---- using this function in "number of threads" at JMX file, the following java code run incorrectly. While using correct numbers it worked. But I want this place can be changeable.

I'm developing a performance testing platform using Jmeter API.

```
StandardJMeterEngine standardJMeterEngine=new StandardJMeterEngine();
System.setProperty(JMeter.JMETER_NON_GUI, "true");
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("D:\software\java\apache-jmeter-5.1\bin\jmeter.properties");
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("D:\software\java\apache-jmeter-5.1\bin\system.properties");
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("D:\software\java\apache-jmeter-5.1\bin\user.properties");
JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("D:\software\java\apache-jmeter-5.1\bin\saveservice.properties");
JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("D:\software\java\apache-jmeter-5.1");
JMeterUtils.initLocale();
JMeterUtils.initLogging();
SaveService.loadProperties();
Properties jmeterProps = JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties();
jmeterProps.put("thread","10");// 
File file=new File("F:\a.jmx");
FileServer.getFileServer().setBase(file);
FileServer.getFileServer().setScriptName(file.getName());
Field baseField = FileServer.getFileServer().getClass().getDeclaredField("base");
baseField.setAccessible(true);//
baseField.set(FileServer.getFileServer(), file.getAbsoluteFile().getParentFile());
HashTree scripts=SaveService.loadTree(file);
Summariser summariser = new Summariser(JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary"));
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summariser);
logger.setFilename("F:\a.jtl");
scripts.add(scripts.getArray()[0],logger);
JMeter.convertSubTree(scripts);
standardJMeterEngine.configure(scripts);
standardJMeterEngine.runTest();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your `{`

```
  ${__P(thread,1)}
```

And 1 is the  [default](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)  so you can use

```
  ${__P(thread)}
```

> The default value for the property. If omitted, the default is set to "1".

Comment: Thanks a lot, there I make a mistake while posting this question,this function spelt correct at my JMX script.

Comment: Or check other options https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46183423/how-to-pass-custom-property-when-running-jmeter-via-java-code-without-editing-th

Comment: emm......I'm reading Jmeter sourcecode, JMeterUtils.setProperty(..) this method have two string variables.and I had tried System.setProperty("thread","10"),it also doesn't work too.

Comment: @jerry.yang add `JMeterUtils.setProperty("thread","10");` before `JMeterUtils.initLocale();`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to explicitly add [ApacheJMeter_functions.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_functions/5.1) to your project [CLASSPATH](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) otherwise neither [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) nor other [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions) will work properly.

Also make sure to escape backslashes like change:

```
logger.setFilename("F:\a.jtl");
```

to

```
logger.setFilename("F:\\a.jtl");
```

or use forward slashes instead:

```
logger.setFilename("F:/a.jtl");
```

More information: [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui/)

Comment: Thanks, I copyed java code from my idea, these places have two \\ in my idea, but have one \ here.